# How to access global variables loaded later with the defer tag?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an application following the architectural model present on the implementation of [OneSignal's Web Push applications](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-quickstart).

Basically, OneSignal asks its user to add two JavaScript codes at the end of the page:

```
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/web/v16/OneSignalSDK.page.js" defer></script>
<script>
  window.OneSignalDeferred = window.OneSignalDeferred || [];
  OneSignalDeferred.push(function(OneSignal) {
    OneSignal.init({
      appId: "YOUR_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID",
    });
  });
</script>
```

The first script refers to `OneSignalSDK.page.js`, which is nothing more than a simple command responsible for adding another script inside the `<head>` tag.

The second one, seems that he uses a existing commands within the script that was imported within the `<head>` tag, in order to make it global through the `window` variable:

```
window.OneSignalDeferred = window.OneSignalDeferred || [];
```

So that he can then use its methods and functions:

```
OneSignalDeferred.push(...);
```

To achieve this type of architectural model, I started by creating my own script that is usually added at the end of my HTML page:

```
<script src="./StackOverflowSDK.page.js" defer></script>
<script>
    window.StackOverflowDeferred = window.StackOverflowDeferred || [];
    console.log('StackOverflowDeferred: ', StackOverflowDeferred);
</script>
```

The code below is my `StackOverflowSDK.page.js`, which is responsible for loading another JavaScript file within the `<head>` tag:

```
(() => {
    "use strict";
    function importSDK(numberVersion){
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.defer = true;
        s.src = "http://localhost/StackOverflow/StackOverflowSDK.page.es6.js?v=".concat(numberVersion);
        document.head.appendChild(s);
    }
    importSDK(10001);
})();
```

Importing the above code works correctly, and the `StackOverflowSDK.page.es6.js` script is implemented inside the `<head>` tag perfectly.

The code below presents the `StackOverflowSDK.page.es6.js` file:

```
(() => {

    class StackClass {
        static init(e){
            //....
        }
    }

    window.StackOverflowDeferred = StackClass;
})();
```

The problem is that the command `window.StackOverflowDeferred = window.StackOverflowDeferred || [];` returns an **empty array** instead of a `StackClass` class reference.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Use [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) and [`import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import)?

Comment: Your `console.log()` executes before the deferred script is loaded. So the assignment `window.StackOverflowDeferred = StackClass;` hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Notice that in the first snippet the reference to `OneSignal` is in a function, not in code that's executed immediately.

Comment: "*my `StackOverflowSDK.page.js` is responsible for loading another JavaScript file `StackOverflowSDK.page.es6.js`*" - don't make it so complicated (and slow)! Just load the second script directly.

Comment: "*`window.StackOverflowDeferred = [];` returns an empty array instead of a `StackClass` class reference.*" - of course it does, that's literally what the code says! But it means you can immediately start pushing items to that array, which your script can then inspect and handle right before it overrides the array with your instance. What do you want to use the `StackClass` for anyway? What is your actual problem that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pattern I personally recognize from GA or GTM, the idea is to have an array-like interface (usually just the `push` method) and to default back to an array before the script is loaded. Once the script is fully loaded, you initialize the actual instance with what was in that variable if it exists.

Essentially, you don't know whether you have the fully-loaded version or not, but it doesn't matter.

```
<script src="./SomeSDK.page.js" defer></script>
<script>
    window.SomeSDKDeferred = window.SomeSDKDeferred || [];
</script>
```

// SomeSDK.page.js

```
(() => {

    class SDK {
        constructor(values) {
            values.forEach(value => this.push(value));
        }

        // [...]

        push(/* [...] */) {
            // [...]
        }

        // [...]
    }

    window.SomeSDKDeferred = new SDK(window.SomeSDKDeferred || []);
})();
```

If you **absolutely** need to have the actual variable, then just load your script using `defer` and position it in the DOM after the `SDK`.

```
<script src="./SomeSDK.page.js" defer></script>
<script src="./someThing/thatDependsOn/SomeSDK.js" defer></script>
```